# how to unlimit the number of group for one user in centos4/5

Tags: linux, centos, nfs

If one user have more than 16 groups, it will cause that the groups don't work for permission control.

How to unlimited this number of groups per user in Centos4/5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *unlimit* the additionnal groups per user. But you can raise the limit. Beware that most Unix systems are limited to 16 groups per user (see http://www.j3e.de/ngroups.html) , so does NFS, see  https://xkyle.com/solving-the-nfs-16-group-limit-problem/ and/or http://nfsworld.blogspot.fr/2005/03/whats-deal-on-16-group-id-limitation.html

The number of group per user is defined by `NGROUPS_MAX` from `<limits.h>` but should be read with `sysconf(_SC_NGROUPS_MAX)`. You can change the kernel maximum group count with `sysctl kernel.ngroupmax` or `/proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max`. But this will require support from C library, PAM and login program.

Comment: Hi ydroneaud,thanks for your good answer. I check the /proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max and the value is 65536. And the problem seems come from NFS

Comment: If nothing in the articles worked, there's a patch at http://www.frankvm.com/nfs-ngroups/ , see http://www.frankvm.com/nfs-ngroups/README